# Create Moq instances for generic types

Tags: c#, generics, moq

I've got an issue setting up a mock (using moq).

We've got a generic repository:

```
public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T>
    where T : EntityBase
{
    public Repository(DbSet<T> set)
    {
        Set = set;
    }

    [...]
}
```

And I would like to dynamically create repositories which will be returned by  our IRepositoryResolver:

```
public interface IRepositoryResolver
{
    TRepository Resolve<TRepository, TEntity>()
        where TRepository : IRepository<TEntity>
        where TEntity : EntityBase;

    IRepository<TEntity> ResolveFor<TEntity>()
        where TEntity : EntityBase;

    IRepository<TEntity> ResolveFor<TEntity>(TEntity entity)
        where TEntity : EntityBase;
}
```

For this, I've implemented these mock setup methods:

```
    private void SetupRepositoryResolverMock()
    {
        var basisDataTypes = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(Basisdata))
            .GetTypes()
            .Where(p => p.IsClass && !p.IsAbstract
                                  && typeof(Basisdata).IsAssignableFrom(p))
            .ToList();

        Basisdata[] basisdataInstances = new Basisdata[basisDataTypes.Count];
        for (int i = 0; i < basisDataTypes.Count; i++)
        {
            basisdataInstances[i] = (Basisdata)Activator.CreateInstance(basisDataTypes.ElementAt(i));
        }

        _repositoryResolverMock = new Mock<IRepositoryResolver>();
        foreach (var basisdataInstance in basisdataInstances)
        {
            Type genericRepository = typeof(Repository<>);
            Type constructedRepository = genericRepository.MakeGenericType(basisdataInstance.GetType());
            var repositoryInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(constructedRepository, GetQueryableMockDbSet(new[] { basisdataInstance }).Object);
            //_repositoryResolverMock
            //    .Setup(x => x.ResolveFor(basisdataInstance))
            //    .Returns(() => repositoryInstance);
        }
    }

    private static Mock<DbSet<T>> GetQueryableMockDbSet<T>(ICollection<T> sourceList) where T : EntityBase
    {
        [...]
    }
```

The data model is: concrete implementations extend abstract Basisdata which extend abstract EntityBase

Now my issue is that the type passed GetQueryableMockDbSet will always return an instance of `Mock<DbSet<Basisdata>>` instead of a DbSet of a concrete implementation on line `var repositoryInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(constructedRepository, GetQueryableMockDbSet(new[] { basisdataInstance }).Object);` which obviously leads to an Exception as `T` does not match for the repository and DBSet.

**Question:** How can I make GetQueryableMockDbSet return a DBset for the correct type?

Note that I want this to be dynamic and don't know all the entities extending Basisdata.

[Edit] here the test and setup methods:

```
    [SetUp]
    public void Setup()
    {
        SetupServiceMock();
        SetupRepositoryResolverMock();
        SetupPersonalModuleMock();

        _onlineSyncServicePersonal = new OnlineSyncServicePersonal(_serviceMock.Object, _repositoryResolverMock.Object, new[] { _personalModuleMock.Object });
    }

    [Test]
    public void CheckoutTest()
    {
        // arrange
        var checkoutRequest = new CheckoutRequest
        {
            DienstId = Guid.NewGuid(),
            OrganisationId = Guid.NewGuid(),
            CheckoutId = Guid.NewGuid(),
            LockModuleNames = new[]
            {
                Constants.ModuleName.BASE,
                Constants.ModuleName.PERSONAL
            }
        };

        // act
        var checkoutResult = _onlineSyncServicePersonal.Checkout(checkoutRequest);

        // assert
    }
```

Comment: Preferably, I don't agree with your approach of creating Mock of  all Repository methods for each entity. You are trying to mock excessively where you don't require. I follow a approach which works on `AAA (Arrange, Act and Assert)` principle. And to validate a test, I `Arrange` the code for those classes/methods are which are part of small unit of test execution. Remember you should not try to mock for everything at once, you should mock for those which you require to validate against a written unit test.

Comment: I also follow the AAA approach. In this case a service layer method shall be tested, which returns entities having to be synchronized between two application instances. For this, these repositories need to be mocked.

Comment: Show the method under test and how it would need/use *all* those mocked repositories. your requirement has a code smell to it that may be because this is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @Nkosi I haven't written the code yet. The goal is to retrieve all entity instances stored in DB, for entities marked with a custom attribute, for synchronization purposes. For this, the repository mocks should return some entities so I can assert that the mocked ones match the ones contained in checkoutResult.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem here is your use of generic methods with implicitly inferred types. Apart from `Basisdata[]` all other type usages are `var` and generics with `<T>` which the compiler all resolves to `Basisdata`. Since `Moq` uses the same mechanism to define the type, instead of looking at the type of the passed object, you end up with `DbSet<Basisdata>`.

You could get around this with a generic mock-builder class which you create with reflection as well. I quickly build this and tested it, tell me if it works for you too:

```
public class MockCreator
{
    public static Mock CreateMock(Type genericType, Type itemType)
    {
        var typeToMock = genericType.MakeGenericType(itemType);
        var creator = typeof(Mock<>).MakeGenericType(typeToMock);
        return (Mock)Activator.CreateInstance(creator);
    }
}


// Usage
var types = new Type[0]; // Your entity types
var sets = types.Select(t => MockCreator.CreateMock(typeof(DbSet<>), t)).ToList();

// Or in your case 
var setMock = MockCreator.CreateMock(typeof(DbSet<>), basisdataInstance.GetType());
```

**Edit:** Reduced code to a single static class that can create the Mocks.

Comment: Thanks, this indeed works! Now I have to figure out the last (commented out) step, where the _repositoryResolverMock is being set up, so that `.Setup(x => x.ResolveFor(basisdataInstance))` returns the correct type and not `BasisData`

Comment: Thanks! Saved me a lot of effort trying to create non-null objects of a given `Type`.